# Users send push notification, firebase cloud messaging

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I want all the users of my app to be able to send me a message, whereby on my device I will get a notifcation. I also want to be able to reply to the user. Its basically like a chat app, with push notifications coming in with each message.

Is Firebase Cloud Messaging right for me. What I have read is that this cloud messaging is when you want to send a message to some or all of your users. But can they reply and send me messages? I have been reading a lot about this buy didn't get a clear answer.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is abstract and unclear too ? can you explain more in detail ?